# Infinite order elements of $G/G^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that $G^k:=\{g^k\mid g\in G\}\triangleleft G$. There exist $G$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $G/G^k$ has an element of infinite order?

It's easy to show that if $G$ is abelian, then every element of $G/G^k$ has finite order. Hence $G$, if exists, is an infinite non-abelian group.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This can not be true.  If $xG^k \in G/G^k$ then 
$$(xG^k)^k = x^kG^k = G^k$$  since $x^k \in G^k$.